# Large images, small resolution

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, designers, pixelation, graphic-styles

I am working on a graduation announcement for a client, and the images they want me to use are huge. They are around 55in by 88in with a resolution of 72. I asked if they had any other format of the pictures besides jpeg and they said no. I am trying to change the resolution then resize the images. Because if I just resize the image it's way too pixelated. Is there anything else I can do? My photoshop keeps crashing when I try to change the resolution before changing the size. I tried doing size first then resolution but those were pixelated too. `

Comment: Switch off the resampling option when you resize.

Answer (score 2):

There are some misunderstandings here. The *Document Size* and the *Resolution* aren't really *attributes* of the image but just *settings*. The only number that really tells us anything about the quality of the image is the *Pixel Dimensions*.

Your images are: `55 x 88 inches @ 72 ppi`, which is means they must have the *Pixel Dimensions* `3960 x 6336 px` (which is large but not exactly *huge*).

If you enter *Image/Image Size* and make sure that *Resample Image* is turned off, you can play around with the settings.

If for example you set the *Resolution* to 300 ppi (which should be good for most types of printing) you get the *Document Size* `13.2 x 21.12 inches`. But notice that the *Pixel Dimensions* are still `3960 x 6336 px`. It is still the *exact* same image. You have only changed the *intent* of the image, not the image itself.

You could also set the *Document Size* to whatever you like. Still doesn't change the image.

The pixels of the image are only changed if you turn on *Resample Image* and in your case there is no need to do that.

Anyway, I don't understand why you worry about this? Aren't you just going to place the image in InDesign or Illustrator and then resize it to the proper size? If you are printing directly from Photoshop (I never do that) can't you just choose the correct printing size when printing? If you are making the whole design in Photoshop can't you just setup a document with the right dimensions then copy/paste in the image and resize it to the appropriate size?

(Btw this issue has nothing to do with the image being a jpeg.)

Comment: I do take the images into illustrator but when I take them there and resize them they still are blurry and then become distorted

Answer (score 1):

I get images like this all the time.  What I usually do is to go into the Image Size Options, turn off resampling, and set the dpi for 300 and set the size to something more reasonable, and closer to the size that I will be working with-say 10in wide.  This should reduce the actual dimensions of your image but still allow you to retain enough content that the images will not be pixilated.